# Doing `whenNew` with Mockito 3.5+ (and without PowerMock)

Tags: mockito, powermock

Before you say it, I know this is a piece of code that is hard to test. It is a legacy that I was going to refactor it at some point, but I just didn't want to do it right now.

---

I am currently in the process of migrating my test cases from PowerMockito as it turned out to be a sort of dead project.

I came upon the challenge of mimicking the behavior I have grown used to with `whenNew`

Use case:

```
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList();
PowerMockito.whenNew(ArrayList.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(numbers);

// The `doStuff` under the hood instantiates `ArrayList`
someService.doStuff();

// Finally, verify 
Assert.assertEquals(numbers.size(), 1);
```

In this particular case, by design, I have no access to this internal `ArrayList`, but I would still very much like to verify its results.

With PowerMockito, I was able to do that, but with Mockito, I am having difficulties matching the behavior. The closest one I've got was:

```
try(MockedConstruction<ArrayList> listConstruction = Mockito.mockConstruction(ArrayList.class, Mockito.withSettings().defaultAnswer(Answers.CALLS_REAL_METHODS))){

    someService.doStuff();

    ArrayList<Integer> numbers = listConstruction.constructed().get(0);
    Assert.assertEquals(numbers.size(), 1);
}
```

In this example, `SomeService` does construct mocked list but:

1. It is not my instance that I created externally (maybe a good thing)
2. The `mockConstruction` does not invoke the original constructor nor does it go over member initialization. This gives me an empty shell object, incapable of doing any real methods for which I get NPE.

Comment: It was pointed out to me that test is more problematic that the implementation itself. The test here wrongly relies on deep-internal state of the service ...

Answer (score 1):

The problem stated in your question is a tricky one and the solution is "hacky" as well, so just to be clear (even though it's been stated in the question as well): I do not recommend using this approach, it would be best to refactor the code and avoid mocking construction of the `ArrayList`. **This answer is more of a "why we shouldn't go that way" showcase**. That being said...

Mockito and the libraries it uses under the hood operate on the `ArrayList` class, which in turn refer back to the Mockito's `MockedConstruction`, which causes a `StackOverflowError` in a scenario I verified. It is a problem also described in the Mockito GitHub Issues: [here](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/2342) and [here](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/2588).

To work around that we may create a method like this:

```java
static <T> MockedConstruction<T> mockCreationOnce(Class<T> clazz) {
    // to operate on the MockedConstruction within a lambda passed to its creation
    // we have to be able to pass the object to the lambda
    // and to do that it needs to be final => AtomicReference usage
    // (it could also be a custom class with a field set at a later time;
    // the reference passed to the lambda has to be final, its contents may change)
    var constructionHolder = new AtomicReference<MockedConstruction<T>>();
    var listConstruction = Mockito.mockConstruction(
            clazz,
            context -> {
                try {
                    return Mockito.withSettings();
                } finally {
                    // we're closing the MockedConstruction after first call
                    // from within the doStuff() method
                    // to avoid the construction being mocked in Mockito internal calls
                    var construction = constructionHolder.get();
                    // we're using closeOnDemand() instead of close() to avoid exceptions here
                    // (no-op if closed already)
                    construction.closeOnDemand();
                }
            }
    );
    // here we're setting the MockedConstruction in the AtomicReference
    // it happens before the lambda call,
    // which will be invoked for the first (and last) time
    // during ArrayList constructor call in the doStuff() method
    constructionHolder.set(listConstruction);
    return listConstruction;
}
```

Thanks to that we can verify the tested code (for example):

```java
void doStuff() {
    var numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    numbers.add(1);
    numbers.add(2);
    numbers.add(3);
}
```

with such a test method:

```java
@Test
void doStuff() {
    var listConstruction = mockCreationOnce(ArrayList.class);

    someService.doStuff();

    var mockedList = listConstruction.constructed().get(0);
    var inOrder = Mockito.inOrder(mockedList);
    inOrder.verify(mockedList).add(1);
    inOrder.verify(mockedList).add(2);
    inOrder.verify(mockedList).add(3);
    Mockito.verifyNoMoreInteractions(mockedList);
}
```

---

If we wanted to use an actual `ArrayList` object as a spy here, it would not be possible, because of the problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37333404/3305737) - that's the source of the `NullPointerException`. To work around that, explicit mocking can be used (which is another hack, showing that this is not the way to operate in the tests). For example for the tested code:

```java
void doStuff() {
    var numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    numbers.add(1);
    numbers.add(2);
    numbers.add(3);
    if (numbers.size() < 3) {
        throw new AssertionError("Impossible state - size: " + numbers.size());
    }
}
```

the test could look like this:

```java
@Test
void doStuff() {
    var listConstruction = mockCreationOnce(ArrayList.class);
    // has to be done in a separate thread
    // because the object needs to be created first in doStuff()
    new Thread(() -> {
        while (listConstruction.constructed().isEmpty()) {
            // busy waiting for the construction to be finished before stubbing
        }
        var mock = listConstruction.constructed().get(0);
        Mockito.doAnswer(inv -> 3)
               .when(mock)
               .size();
    }).start();

    someService.doStuff();

    // no exception is thrown
}
```

Without the stubbing the test fails with `AssertionError`. An important caveat regarding the snippet above: the stubbing mechanism needs polishing because now it's subject to a race condition and "random" test failure - some locking mechanism would have to be used to work around that. Still - in my opinion it would be simplest to work towards a proper solution instead of stacking workarounds in the tests.

---

I recreated the code above in [a GitHub repository](https://github.com/Jonarzz/stack-overflow/commit/d5cfaea553412befebe676b9072299ed0820142c). I verified it - the test passes.