# mockito Call real methods

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito

I have this test:
but the method checkIfHold is also mocked

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class FrontSecurityServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private FrontSecurityService frontSecurityService
            = mock( FrontSecurityService.class, withSettings().defaultAnswer(CALLS_REAL_METHODS));

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        when(frontSecurityService.getLoggedInUserId()).thenReturn("000");
        frontSecurityService.checkIfHold(9L);
    }
}
```

I also tried with

```
   @Mock
    PerService perService;
    @Spy
    private FrontSecurityService frontSecurityService = new FrontOfficeSecurityService(perService);
```

but then is not mocking the method `getLoggedInUserId()`, getLoggedInUserId is public, non-static, and non-final.

I also tried, there it works, but MenService is called inside checkIfHold is null

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class FrontSecurityServiceTest {

    @Mock
    MenService menService;
    @Mock
    FrontSecurityService frontSecurityService;
    @Rule
    public MockitoRule rule = MockitoJUnit.rule();


    @Test
    public void test1() {

        MenReturn menReturn1 = MenReturn.builder().build();
        when(menService.getMen(anyString(), anyLong())).thenReturn(Arrays.asList(menReturn1));
         when(frontSecurityService.checkIfHold(anyLong())).thenCallRealMethod();
when(frontSecurityService.getLoggedInUserId()).thenReturn("000");
        frontSecurityService.checkIfHold(9L);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that `@Spy` is what you are looking for. Still, testing `FrontSecurityService` and also mock it at the same time seems odd to me.
Try the following:

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class FrontSecurityServiceTest {

    @Spy
    private FrontSecurityService frontSecurityService;

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        when(frontSecurityService.getLoggedInUserId()).thenReturn("000");
        frontSecurityService.checkIfHold(9L);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, I only want to test 1 method and the rest mocked

Comment: Please @João Dias let correct this code: you have added a not necessary ')' and the code doesn't compile. Another point: with `@Spy` annotation and the correct `Runner` you already added, you don't need to invokate the constructor

Comment: Thanks for the hints @Renato! I did in fact a duplicated `)`. Regarding your second point, I was not aware of this. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, for FrontSecurityServiceTest, you should not be mocking FrontSecurityService. That's your system-under-test, and you don't want to test your mock, you want to test the system you're testing.

As in my other answer on [Difference between Mockito @Spy and @Mock(answer = Answers.CALLS_REAL_METHODS)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33516324/1426891), if you've mocked with `CALLS_REAL_METHODS`, then you're going to interact with your system (FrontSecurityService) where it has not run any constructors and has not initialized any fields. It is extremely unlikely that FrontSecurityService will work as expected like that.

As with [João Dias's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69497317/1426891), `@Spy` is what you're looking for. As in the docs, you don't need to call the constructor explicitly, but only because [`@Spy` is documented to do so for you](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/Spy.html). If you don't have a zero-arg constructor, `@Spy` will require you to call your constructor, so calling the constructor is not a bad habit to get into—especially if you're using a dependency injection framework or some other context where the constructor might gain parameters later. Your IDE doesn't understand Mockito and will not detect that the constructor is being called reflectively.

Once you have a `@Spy`, things should work as you expect—provided that `getLoggedInUserId` is `public`, non-`static`, and non-`final`.

Answer (score 0):

The first issue I think is that you are using the `@Mock` annotation and also using `Mockito.mock(...)` at the same time.
You can mock an object, then tell Mockito which methods should execute the real implementation

Try the following:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class FrontSecurityServiceTest {

    private FrontSecurityService frontSecurityService = Mockito.mock(FrontSecurityService.class);

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        when(frontSecurityService.getLoggedInUserId()).thenReturn("000");
        when(frontSecurityService.checkIfHold(Mockito.any())).thenCallRealMethod();
        frontSecurityService.checkIfHold(9L);
    }
}
```

If `checkIfHold` method returns void then you have to do something like the following:

```
Mockito.doCallRealMethod().when(frontSecurityService).checkIfHold(Mockito.any());
```

Comment: inside frontSecurityService I use another service that I mock, but I get a nullpointer when accessing to it :-(

Comment: Since it is a mock it would not have your other service wired up. One option is to manually wire it up with something like frontSecurityService.setMyOtherService(myOtherServiceMock)